# Is the "e" character used to denote an invalid number in graphics data?

Tags: numerical

I've got a graphical program that's exporting a data file with numbers such as: `-1.33227e-015` and `-4.02456e-016`.

I've long been perplexed by the "e-" notation. Is it used to denote an invalid number? What sort of valid value can I extract from the above numbers? What are they trying to say?

Comment: Those big negative numbers indicate that the numbers are very, very small, and probably should have been rounded to zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`e` means "× 10^". It standard for **e**xponent.

e.g. `1.33227e-015` means 1.33227 × 10<sup>-15</sup> and `-4.02456e-016` means -4.02456 × 10<sup>-16</sup>.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation for detail.

Answer (score 4):

No. It signifies [exponential/scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_Notation). `-4.02456e-016` means `-4.02456` divided by 10 to the power 16.

Answer (score 3):

`e` or `E` stands for exponent.  Just like x10^ (in written mathematics).  The number following tells you how far the decimal place is moving, (+ for left, - for right) so your above number:

`-1.33227e-015`

Becomes:

`-.00000000000000133227`

While:

`-4.02456e-016`

Becomes:

`-.000000000000000402456`

Answer (score 0):

That is [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#Engineering_notation) being used to represent extremely "large" or "small" numbers.